# Radio buttons random selection ? - Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, random, selenium-ide

I would like to know how to randomly select 1 and also how to randomly select somewhere between 1-6 choices in radio buttons/checkfields on my website using selenium IDE.

I already have a script which can make a random selection in a dropdown menu and this is working fine - can this be easily modified to make these other selections ? 
(please include code examples as I'm a rookie)

Thanks for your help.

```
    <tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>frontrudestatus</td>
    <td>elementId</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//select[@name='${elementId}']/child::option</td>
    <td>elementCount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.floor(Math.random() * (${elementCount}-1))+1</td>
    <td>randomIndex</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>xpath=(//select[@name='${elementId}'])</td>
    <td>index=${randomIndex}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//input[@name='NAME']</td>
    <td>total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.floor(Math.random() * ${total} )+1</td>
    <td>index</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//input[@id='NAME'])[${index}]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

First, you need to get the total number of radion buttons available with name attribute and do randomize.